# Stealling access token via third-party app

Tags: security, oauth, redirect

Let's say we have a website (example.com) , after create account on this site you can log in to your account by visiting your-domain.example.com. Now, after I logged in to my-domain.example.com, I ask to connect to my social account. The `request_token` link which is created by the website is looks like this:

```
https/://www.social-website.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=appid&redirect_uri=https/://mydomain.example.com
```

Now they configure the `redirect_uri` to accept anything like `anything.example.com`.

So, if an attacker set the `redirect_uri` to something `attacker.example.com` and sends the link to victim. If the victim already is authorized the application before he will be redirected automatically to `attacker.example.com` with an access token. If not he will be asked first to authorize the app.

After that attacker will be able to manage the victim's social account. Is this a security issue for the social website?

Answer (score 0):

If this is true OAuth with a JWT, there is something called the `client_secret` that can encrypt/decrpyt the token. For an attacker unless the encrpytion key is stolen too, the jwt is useless and the attacker can't do much with the client id.

Comment: This is a true OAuth i have discovered when i hunting in the third-party website <br>
i don't know lot about "JWT" , but i think it dosen't matter.
I have already test this attack and once victim authorize the app.
I can publish on his account and see messages.

Comment: Did you actually succeed in stealing their client secret? JWT is a standard for transferring credentials (this is encrypted by secret) across the wire.

Comment: No i don't think that i stealing JWT.
But why i need to steal it , since i can get access to victim account?!

Comment: That url won't do jack for you cause to actually access the account you need to combine the client url params with the client secret.

Comment: This is the original request_token link :

https/://www.socail-website.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=app-id&redirect_uri=https/://my-domain.example.com?S={my-sessionid-in-example.com]&state=0ece190d8fc2f42ecba16d24bc90773694a6138b&scope=manage_pages,publish_pages,read_page_mailboxes&display=popup
if a send this link above to any user, once he authorize the app
i will get access to his socail-account

Comment: After he authorize the app, the service provider sends the user back to the original site with url param ids, you need to trade those ids and include the client secret key to access the account. Unless you get that client secret key you will literally have nothing of value.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with OAuth 2.0 but to mitigate this it is strongly recommended to register/whitelist Redirect URIs and use confidential Clients (i.e. Clients that have a client secret) when possible. See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.6

> When requesting authorization using the authorization code grant
> type, the client can specify a redirection URI via the "redirect_uri"
> parameter.  If an attacker can manipulate the value of the
> redirection URI, it can cause the authorization server to redirect
> the resource owner user-agent to a URI under the control of the
> attacker with the authorization code.
>
> ...
>
> In order to prevent such an
> attack, the authorization server MUST    ensure that the redirection
> URI used to obtain the authorization code    is identical to the
> redirection URI provided when exchanging the    authorization code for
> an access token.  The authorization server    MUST require public
> clients and SHOULD require confidential clients    to register their
> redirection URIs.  If a redirection URI is provided    in the request,
> the authorization server MUST validate it against the    registered
> value.